# can't scrape the page using request module not working with flask API with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, flask, beautifulsoup, python-requests

here i'm using flask api module

```
@app.route('/url', methods=['GET'])
def api_url():
    if 'web_url' in request.args:
        web_url = str(request.args['web_url'])

    html = requests.get(web_url).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
    web_page = soup.get_text().strip()
    
    return (web_page)
```

when i give

http://127.0.0.1:5000/url?url=https://stackoverflow.com
it's not scraping the webpage , but it's perfectly working with out API

like example

```
html = requests.get(web_url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
web_page = soup.get_text().strip()
print(web_page)
```

and here i just make
`import request as requests` is that will a issue.? with `request.args`
i just need the scraped web page html code as a output that is i'm searching
like when we do on `google crome view page source`  like that way i'm trying to get output

any suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should import request from flask
and to send the request you, need to import requests

```
import flask  # to get the args and run the http server
import requests # to send the get request
@app.route('/url', methods=['GET'])
def api_url():
    if 'web_url' in flask.request.args:
        web_url = str(flask.request.args['web_url'])

     html = requests.get(web_url).text
     soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
     web_page = soup.get_text().strip()

     return (web_page)
```